# Plotly - change file title of the downloaded graphic

Tags: shiny, plotly

I'am  using the R package plotly in my shiny application.
Here is a small example:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("event")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # renderPlotly() also understands ggplot2 objects!
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt)
  })

  output$event <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (is.null(d)) "Hover on a point!" else d
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I click on the icon to download the graphic, the name of the graphic is "newplot":
[image]

How can I change the name "newplot(27)" by for example "ResultDNA(27)"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are two solutions:

1. By using export function in plotly

   App1 <- plot_ly()

   export(App1 , file = "ResultDNA(27).png")
2. You can 1st save the image in HTML and then in desired format using htmlwidgets

   App2 <- plot_ly(...)

   htmlwidgets::saveWidget(App2, file = "ResultDNA(27).html")

Comment: Thanks Rahul Agarwal. Very helpfull!

Comment: I have tried your solution but it doesn't work. I had to install pandoc and after that I have the following errors: This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Please specify either 'title' or 'pagetitle' in the metadata.
  Falling back to 'ResultDNA'
 Error in UseMethod: pas de méthode pour 'ggplotly' applicable pour un objet de classe "NULL".

Comment: Please check these links it may help you: https://plot.ly/r/static-image-export/   https://github.com/wch/webshot/